# How do I know if a website is using Java EE / J2EE? Any major companies using it?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm doing a bit of research for a school paper, and I need to detect if some websites (Apple, Dropbox, Lego...) are using Java EE / J2EE platform.

The problem is that most of websites hide this by using an intermediate server. Is there any way to confirm they're using Java EE platform?

I know if there's a cookie which starts by "JSESSION..." means that they are indeed using java, but there are just a few that use it.

Also, it would be of great help if you know of some major websites that are using Java EE and their reasons for it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is right for SO but I can't put my finger on the reason why.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't bet on this, less so for major websites that are more likely to use "web-scale" architectures where the notion of "uses J2EE" doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Because at that point your system is likely to be a whole mess of loosely coupled components and services and it's not very likely all of them or even most of them will be using a technology that falls under the same umbrella label. Consider the notorious "incident" where Twitter switched from using Ruby on Rails for their business logic and reimplemented it as a Scala service. Then later got redesigned to the infamous hashbang URL approach that mostly uses Javascript to render content fetched from JSON services over AJAX.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name With a setup like that, is Twitter a Rails application? Is it a Scala application? Is it a Javascript application? It's all of those and neither of those, since it consists of at least those three components that I know of, each based on a completely different technology. And for all we know a whole bunch of other hidden components and services, and some of the ones I mentioned might be implemented in something else by now. So, in your opinion, what would make a non-monolithic system like that "an X application" for any chosen value of X?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name And I posit that for any big, "old" company even their web-facing stuff will be structured that way, if for no practical reason then for historical ones.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You missed or ignored the entire point of my example. I chose Twitter not because it's "not Java" (which isn't even true these days), I chose Twitter because enough of their architecture and how it evolved over time is publically known to serve as such an example. (Since most companies don't really bother blogging / giving talks about their architectural shakeups.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think I was pretty clear about what I meant by *web-scale* too: an architecture that's split up into multiple  loosely coupled subsystems, so that any given subsystem can be scaled out as appropriate. Those subsystems communicate using some sort of web services / APIs, each can be written using a different language / technology, and thus they can be upgraded or rewritten independently of one another, leading to a heterogenous environment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, now you're ignoring my *second* comment. It doesn't rule out anything, my question is would you call such a site as "using the Java EE platform"? If what they're really doing is, say, implementing their payment processing stuff as a bunch of JAX-WS services because most of the backends still use RPC-encoded services which are best consumed by AXIS 1.x. (Without actively going for "technically correct is the best kind of correct" here.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My point here, and where I was going for with "this makes no sense", is that Java EE is an umbrella spec consisting of many technologies. Now, you can have fairly monolithic systems that are pretty much married to Java EE and you can clearly say that those are "Java EE applications". But there's also this whole huge grey area where you can argue semantics until the cows come home. And I'd say a lot of the notable tech companies are very much in this grey area. (Say, IBM and Oracle notwithstanding, it's a safe bet most of /their/ web stuff is Java-based.)

Comment: @millimoose: OK, *now* I get it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably sites with pages which end in : **.do, .action, .jsp, .jsf, .faces** are using Java. Of course, others can be faked or url-remapped.